# Android - What I want is when device is rotated, FragmentActivity is still kept

Tags: android

What I want is, that when the device is rotated, `FragmentActivity` is being still kept.

Im using a `WebView` in a `FragmentActivity` and I have configured `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` for the `FragmentActivity` in the `Manifest.xml` - but when I rotate the device, the `Activity` crashes.

`main.java`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){      
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

`tab1.java`:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    Context mContext;
    WebView web ;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab1, container, false);
        web = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());

        WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

        web.loadUrl("http://google.com");

        //웹뷰에서 뒤로가기
        web.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }); 
        return mainView;
    }
}
```

I want to keep webview every time I rotate my phone. 
Any advise about it?

Answer (score 0):

Something to keep in mind, is on rotate the app will call `onCreate`. So it is essentially recreating your app every time you rotate. So to fix this; (I think) you need to save the state of your app in `savedInstanceState`, then after rotate just resume your state from that.

Answer (score 0):

If you already specified in the manifest that you will handle orientation changed, and you don't want to go through the regular life cycle, in the configuration change do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){      
       super.onConfigurationChanged(null);
}
```

Also if all you want is to retain the instance of your fragment, you could call the method:

```
Fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
```

Which as per googles Documentation "Controls whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration change)."

Regards!

Comment: Fragment.setRetainInstance(true);